# Not able to Load Bootstrap tabs remotely

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Hi I am having difficulties in finding out how to load contents into bootstrap tabs remotely in my ASP.NET MVC project. I did some research and find out this [link](http://www.bootply.com/63891).

I tried to implement this to my project but I am having problem in loading pages properly. I am getting two layouts overlapping one below other and displaying contents of two pages in same time even before I click on link.

This is my code :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#controller1" data-url="http://localhost:1234/controller1/viewname1">Tab1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#Controller2" data-url="http://localhost:1234/controller2/viewname2">Tab2</a></li>

</ul>

 <div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="controller1"></div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="Controller2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And script is :

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
   {


     $('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();

         var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
         var href = this.hash;
         var pane = $(this);

         // ajax load from data-url
         $(href).load(url, function (result) {
             pane.tab('show');
         });
     });

       // load first tab content
     $('#controller1').load($('.active a').attr("data-url"), function (result) {
         $('.active a').tab('show');
     });
```

Here whats happening is, my default controller is controller1. so when i load page, i am getting contents both from controller1 and controller2 that is view1 and view2. 
And also one more thing I should mention here is, I am using same layout page in view like Layout = Layoutname for both view1 and view2.

Can anyone help me in solving this issue.

Comment: You shouldn't specify a Layout in your "tabs" (Layout=null), as they are partial. And your controllers need to return a PartialView()

Answer (score 1):

Modify your click handler to this:

```
$('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
     var href = $(this).attr("href");
     var that = this;

     // ajax load from data-url
     $(href).load(url, function (result) {
         $(that).tab('show');
     });
 });
```

Comment: HI i used your method. My question is what I am supposed to add in place of id?? that is attr("id")? and when i add your code then my second tabs doesnt work?

Comment: @Ajay sorry, modified example. Use attr("href") to get id of target tab.

Comment: Hi I changed to href. Now it goes to other controller in debug mode and it doesnt change view and will stay on same page. can you help me in this?

Comment: @Ajay modified example. Added var that = this;

Comment: Hi sorry for bugging you. Now I am getting same error which i had before that is I am getting tab1 result below tab2 when i go to tab2 menu. what mistake I am doing here.

Comment: @Ajay whith version of bootstrap you are using? Example you reference in your question uses v2.3.2. Last version is 3.2.0 Look [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) for a complete docs for bootstrap tabs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61413/discussion-between-ajay-and-aleha).